# rubyで、レコードの特定の値でソートするには

Tags: ruby-on-rails

以下のようなeventsテーブルがあります。

```
t.string "event_title"
t.date "event_date"
t.string "event_place"
t.text "event_content"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
```

すべての値を@eventsに代入します。

`@events = Event.all`

これを`@event.each`で一覧表示する際に、`event_date`の昇順で表示させるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@events.sort_by(&:event_date).each do |e|
   hogehoge e
end
```

みたいな感じでいけると思います。

Comment: できました！ありがとうございました！
これで年が越せます！TT

Comment: 解決に至った場合には、よろしければ承認いただけると。良いお年を！